# HERE Maps Routing API v8: Street attributes

Tags: here-api

I'm requesting a route through HERE Maps Routing API v8 currently like this

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey={{someapikey}}&return=polyline&spans=functionalClass,streetAttributes&origin=38.577482,-121.858775&destination=38.682991,-121.576498&transportMode=truck'
```

This returns result containing functionalClass and attributes of roads like this:

```
// ...
"spans": [
    {
        "offset": 0,
        "streetAttributes": [
            "rightDrivingSide"
        ],
        "functionalClass": 4
    },
    {
        "offset": 205,
        "streetAttributes": [
            "rightDrivingSide",
            "dividedRoad"
        ],
        "functionalClass": 1
    }
// ...
```

Which is great, but is there anywhere list of possible values for streetAttributes? I found only https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/RoadElement.Attribute.html which is similar to certain degree, but would be great to know different values streetAttributes returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is documented, but you may miss it. When you go to the API Reference (https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.6.4/api-reference-swagger.html), you need to click to open the 200 OK response, and each subkey of the response has to be clicked as well. If you dig down, you get to the docs for streetAttributes which I'm copying here:

```
StreetAttributes is applied to a span of a route section and describes attribute flags of a street.

rightDrivingSide: Do vehicles have to drive on the right-hand side of the road or the left-hand side.
dirtRoad: This part of the route has an un-paved surface.
tunnel: This part of the route is a tunnel.
bridge: This part of the route is a bridge.
ramp: This part of the route is a ramp (usually connecting to/from/between highways).
motorway: This part of the route is a controlled access road (usually highways).
roundabout: This part of the route is a roundabout.
underConstruction: This part of the route is under construction.
dividedRoad: This part of the route uses a road with a physical or legal divider in the middle.
privateRoad: This part of the route uses a privately owned road.
As it is possible that new street attributes are supported in the future, unknown street attributes should be ignored.
```